# Manhwa in which the female lead is a witch who loses her limbs, then is sent back to the past

Tags: story-identification, manga

I'm desperate. I vaguely remember the beginning.

The female lead (villainess?) kills or framed by her fiancé because she is a witch. I think there is war or power struggle happening with the kingdom?

As punishment, they exiled her and removed her arms and leg. She lived in a tent being taken care by a man, I think is the lead male she thought have died just badly injured. There was some sort of an agreement because she is sent back to the past to change her fate. She decides to dump her fiancé and marry the lead male, who is a power soldier she decided to save??

In the last chapter I remember, they got married and on their way to the lead male's hometown.

I think she had white hair or pastel if that helps.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Is this ***[The Villainess Lives Again](https://www.anime-planet.com/manga/the-villainess-lives-again)***...?

> From childhood, Artezia Rosan's happiness was dependent on ensuring the success of her brother. As a master manipulator and schemer, she became his most valuable ally in seizing the empire’s throne. That’s exactly why her brother's betrayal cut so deeply when Artezia was imprisoned as punishment for all of her crimes. Soon after being rescued by Grand Duke Cedric Ebron, she vows to help him overthrow the cruel new emperor by sacrificing her own life with forbidden magic. Now waking up several years earlier back in time, she will forsake her own family to help Cedric at all costs. They say that blood is thicker than water, but can Artezia destroy her brother while her own romance blossoms amidst the chaos?
>
> [image: Promotional art for "The Villainess Lives Again."]

The blonde-haired female lead, [Artizea "Tia" Rosan](https://the-villainess-lives-twice.fandom.com/wiki/Artizea_Rosan), is a villainess who helped her elder brother, [Lawrence](https://the-villainess-lives-twice.fandom.com/wiki/Lawrence_Rosan), become Emperor, but was then framed by him for the murder of his young son, Abe, leading to her being imprisoned and having her limbs and tongue cut off.

She's subsequently freed by a subordinate of the male lead, [Grand Duke Cedric Ebron](https://the-villainess-lives-twice.fandom.com/wiki/Cedric_Evron), who takes her to a tent in his military camp, where he asks her to help devise a plan to end Emperor Lawrence's tyrannical reign.

After being left alone in the tent, she bites the insides of her cheeks, uses her blood to draw a magic circle on the ground with her mouth, and is regressed several years back in time, prior to her brother having become Emperor.

Comment: Omg yes!! Thank you so much! I've been looking for this for months!